# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on popviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, exc-bad-access

I have 3 ViewControllers `A,B and C`. When I do `B -> A`, it doesn't give any error. But when I do `A->B->C->B->A` it gives an error when popping ViewController B when I opened ViewController C. This error doesn't occur when I did not open ViewController C. This is what I get from the Instrument Zombie Profiler:

```
An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated 'CViewController' object (zombie) at address: 0x1b593340.
```

I am using ARC on Xcode 5.1 testing my device on an iPhone 5s.

I do

```
CViewController *vc = [[CViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

to go to the next ViewController

and `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` to go back.

Comment: Do you have any delegate? Or Did you write any code on ViewWill disappear? Just put breakpoint and track that crash location. Above code seems to be ok.

Comment: I do have a number of delegates for UISearchBar, UITableView, UIScrollView on the interface builder set up but never really had any problem with them before. I also have programmatically made UITableViews with set delegate that didn't cause any problem too. I tried setting their delegates to nil but with no success.

Comment: Actually `PreviewPlaylistViewController` is belong to `B` or `A`?!!

Comment: Sorry about not pointing that out in my question, it is ViewController "C"

Comment: Confusion by changing your crash log.  `CViewController` is ViewController C, and now you got this error log when you pop C and go back to B? Am I right?

Comment: Nope. Popping from B to A is ok if C was not opened once in the app. But popping from B to A crashes if C was previously opened. Like in my example A->B->C->B->A causes crash.

Comment: Show some code placed in Viewcontroller B which should related to C. For ex. you may have block which may hold C in B..

Comment: I got it now. It seems that I had a delegate in my BasicViewController class, I solved it by setting it to nil at viewWillDisappear. Thanks for helping me out @Mani. I was getting crazy over this.

Comment: Then check my answer and let me know whether helpful or not.